# How to access model in bundle block class?

Tags: magento2, bundle, bundle-product

I have overwrited the bundle class usig di.xml

```
  preference for="Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle"type="Bachus\BundleContextPros\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle" />
```

in my custom module. Now I want to write a method in this class which will create my model (Bunleset) wchih I created In my cusotm module. I want to get some data form my custom table here.

my method in Bachus\BundleContextPros\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle.php

```
class Bundle extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AbstractView
{
 ...

 public function generateJsContext(){
        $model = new \Bachus\BundleContextPros\Model\Bundleset();

        foreach($this->getOptions() as $option){

            $title =  $option->getTitle();

            }
        return $title;
    }
```

but I get error like that:

Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Model\Context, none given, called in

I know my model bundleset class, reasourcecollection etc. are ok beacuse I have followed Alanstorm CRUD tutoral And I can fetch the data in example blocks. But I need this data in Bundle class method to then display it on option.phtml. Please Help

Comment: Show your full class.

Answer (score 0):

I fund the ansver which works

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$model = $objectManager->create('\Namespace\Modulename\Model\Modulename');
```

but on the oter topic people say that is not recomened and I schould overide _constructor so I did:

```
public function __construct(

    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayUtils $arrayUtils,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $catalogProduct,
    \Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\PriceFactory $productPrice,
    \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
    \Bachus\BundleContextPros\Model\Bundleset $bundlset, // my class

    array $data = []
) {

    $this->catalogProduct = $catalogProduct;
    $this->productPriceFactory = $productPrice;
    $this->jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
    $this->localeFormat = $localeFormat;
    $this->bundleset = $bundlset; /// My custom model wich i want to load
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $arrayUtils,
        $data
    );
}
```

but I get errors

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 7 passed to Bachus\BundleContextPros\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle::__construct() must be an instance of Bachus\BundleContextPros\Model\Bundleset, array given, called in

Any Idea?